# MYSQL - Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

When I am running a query like that it works perfectly:

```
SELECT 10 as a;
```

But when I am using the column a

```
SELECT 10 as a, (a - 1) as b
```

I get following error: Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'

Why isn't it working that way?

Comment: You can't use an alias in the same select query

Comment: because `a` is not a column

Comment: "An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses to refer to the column" ([Problems with Column Aliases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't reuse an alias in the same `SELECT` statement in which it was defined.  Perhaps the closest thing to what you want to do here would be this:

```
SELECT
    t.a,
    (t.a - 1) AS b
FROM (SELECT 10 AS a FROM dual) t;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also be using user variables.

```
SET @a := 10;
SELECT
     @a AS a
  , (@a - 1) AS b
FROM DUAL;
```

Rewritten to one query

```
SELECT
     @a AS a
  , (@a - 1) AS b
FROM
 (SELECT @a := 10) AS init_user_param ;
```

**More optimal**

SELECT
    10 AS a
   , 9 AS b
FROM
 DUAL;

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below.

```
select t1.a,(t1.a-1) as b from  (SELECT 10 as a) t1;
```